# What does the unitary $[|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes(|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle1|)]\otimes I$ represent?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises

Consider the following unitary defined for a system $A$ interacting with a bipartite system $BB^\prime$

$$U_{AB} =  \Big[|0\rangle \langle 0|_{A} \otimes \mathbf{I}_{B} + |1\rangle \langle 1|_{A} \otimes \big(|1\rangle \langle 0|_{B} +  |0\rangle \langle 1|_{B} \big) \Big] \otimes \mathbf{I}_{B^\prime},$$ with
$\mathbf{I}_i$ being the identity.

My question:

1. What is the physical meaning of operation $U_{AB}$?
2. Can one represent $U_{AB}$ in terms of quantum logic gates ( a circuit diagram)?

Comment: The expression inside the square brackets is just a CNOT from A to B. It is usually considered to be an elementary gate, so it's representation is just itself.

Comment: I guess the "key" observation is that $| 1 \rangle \langle  0 |_{B} + | 0 \rangle \langle  1 |_{B} = \sigma^x_{B}$

Answer (score 1):

The gate/operator in the brackets is the non-local CNOT gate, frequently used to create bipartite entanglement. Given it itself is a 2 qubit gate, then the tensor of this with the identity is simply a gate that acts on 3 qubits.

This gate will take a 3 qubit state and flip the second qubit of this state when the first is $|1\rangle$ It will take $|110\rangle \to|100\rangle, |111\rangle \to |101\rangle$ and vice-versa.

Edit: important to note is that $|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle 1|$ is the Pauli X gate

Comment: what you mean with "non-local CNOT gate"? It's just a normal CNOT

Comment: Yes, and a normal CNOT gate is non-local. It is used frequently to introduce non-local correlations.